# Android animated button size change from both sides

Tags: android, animation, button, android-animation

Android animation
How to change button size from both sides (Left and Right)
in the same time 
As this image

[image: Image sample]

I tried this .. but it doesn't work like what I wish

```
public void scaleView(View v, float startScale, float endScale) {
    Animation anim = new ScaleAnimation(
            startScale, endScale, // Start and end values for the X axis scaling
            1f, 1f, // Start and end values for the Y axis scaling
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0f, // Pivot point of X scaling
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 1f); // Pivot point of Y scaling
    anim.setFillAfter(true); // Needed to keep the result of the animation
    anim.setDuration(3000);
    v.startAnimation(anim);
}
```

Comment: Did you try to do it somehow ?

Comment: Change your x pivot scaling point from 0f to 0.5f

Answer (score 1):

Change pivotXValue to 0.5

```
    public void scaleView(View v, float startScale, float endScale) {
            Animation anim = new ScaleAnimation(
            startScale, endScale, // Start and end values for the X axis scaling
            1f, 1f, // Start and end values for the Y axis scaling
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, // Pivot point of X scaling
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 1f); // Pivot point of Y scaling
            anim.setFillAfter(true); // Needed to keep the result of the animation
            anim.setDuration(3000);
            v.startAnimation(anim);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Did you try this:

```
v.animate().setDuration(3000).scaleX(endScale);
```

Comment: Did it not work or did it mislead? wondering the reason for downvote!